# Garbage data in file after sudden power loss

Tags: filesystems, fat32

I am using a flash with FAT32 system. I am continuosly writing data to a file using file system APIs from rtos(SMX). However, after sudden poweroffs, the file contains garbage values just above the first file entry on system reboot.

I run chkdsk utility, but it doesn't fix any problem.

Any idea how can i get rid of these garbage entries even on unclean power offs?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect sudden power loss, you'll need to disable all caching/buffering on file writes.  Of course you'll also need to deal with partially-written files, but that should at least prevent trailing garbage.

I don't know the API you're using, but this might be done by mounting the drive "synchronously" (e.g., `mount -o sync` in Linux) or by opening individual files with specific options.  If you do disable buffering on individual file writes, you may still run the risk of corrupting the FAT, however, and losing all the files.

Comment: I do not expect sudden power loss, however, I need to make sure that everyting is written to this file and there should not be any garbage data.

Comment: If you can't say that it won't happen, e.g., because of a backup power supply, then you "expect it to happen" in practice.